Why doesn't Redux Persist store data in localStorage
I am using Next.js and trying to use Redux Persist to save data so it remains even after a page refresh. However, when I refresh the page, the old data is gone. I'm not sure where I'm making a mistake with Redux Persist. Here is my code. I’ve also tried a few solutions from Stack Overflow, but they didn’t work.
store.tsx
// components/redux/store.js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import treeReducer from './uiSlice';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'treeRoot',
  storage,
  whitelist: ['tree'], // Only persist the `tree` slice
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, treeReducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    tree: persistedReducer,
  },
});

const persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export default store;


provider.tsx
// components/redux/ClientProvider.js
"use client";

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import store, { persistor } from './store';

interface ClientProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export default function ClientProvider({ children }: ClientProviderProps) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        {children}
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}

my slicer
// components/redux/treeSlice.js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  treeCount: 0,
  isTreeLover: true,
};

const treeSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'tree',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    plantTree: (state) => {
      state.treeCount += 1;
    },
    chopTree: (state) => {
      state.treeCount = state.treeCount > 0 ? state.treeCount - 1 : 0;
    },
    toggleTreeLover: (state) => {
      state.isTreeLover = !state.isTreeLover;
    },
  },
});

export const { plantTree, chopTree, toggleTreeLover } = treeSlice.actions;
export default treeSlice.reducer;

my component
"use client";
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { plantTree, chopTree, toggleTreeLover } from '@/components/redux/uiSlice';
import { RootState } from '@/components/redux/store';

export default function TreeComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const treeCount = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.tree.treeCount);
  const isTreeLover = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.tree.isTreeLover);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Initial state:', { treeCount, isTreeLover });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-screen">
      <h1>Tree Tracker</h1>
      <p>Tree Count: {treeCount}</p>
      <p>Are you a Tree Lover? {isTreeLover ? "Yes" : "No"}</p>

      <button onClick={() => dispatch(plantTree())} className="m-2 p-2 bg-green-500 text-white rounded">
        Plant a Tree 
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(chopTree())} className="m-2 p-2 bg-red-500 text-white rounded">
        Chop a Tree 
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(toggleTreeLover())} className="m-2 p-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded">
        Toggle Tree Lover 
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}


Do you mind using context api?
